# Pytorch TypeError - eq() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I'm working on a text classification problem with BERT. When training on the local machine everything works just fine, but when switching to the server, I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-28-508d35ac5f5f> in flat_accuracy(preds, labels)
      5     pred_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
      6     labels_flat = labels.flatten()
----> 7     return np.sum(pred_flat == labels_flat) / len(labels_flat)
      8 
      9 # Function to calculate the f1_score of our predictions vs labels

TypeError: eq() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (numpy.ndarray), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (numpy.ndarray)
 * (Number other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (numpy.ndarray)
```

Code:

```
def flat_accuracy(preds, labels):
    pred_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
    labels_flat = labels.flatten()
    return np.sum(pred_flat == labels_flat) / len(labels_flat)
```

Torch version on local machine: `1.4.0`

Torch version on the server: `1.3.1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the `eq` implementation of the torch version on your server no longer lets you do elementwise comparison between a `torch.Tensor` and a `np.ndarray`. You should coerce either `pred_flat` to be a `torch.Tensor`, or coerce `labels_flat` to be a numpy array. Since you're using `np.sum` in the return statement and you are just returning a scalar value, I'd just move everything to numpy, so

```
labels_flat = labels.numpy()
```

but if you're on the GPU you may need to call `labels.cpu().numpy()`, and if you're tracking gradients on labels you might need `labels.detach().cpu().numpy()`.